# Python Selenium finding element (input)

Tags: python

I was trying to get the xpath of an input what type shall i use ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ6Nw.png)

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome:

Right click an element -> Inpect Element -> Right click the source code -> Copy -> Copy XPath